# How to tell if pc.onnegotiationneeded was fired because stream has been removed?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, sdp, peer-connection

I am dealing with a [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) (`pc`) which has an event handler named [onnegotiationneeded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onnegotiationneeded).

The "`onnegotiationneeded`" is triggered when a complete media stream is added or removed with `pc.addStream` or `pc.removeStream`.

Is it possible to tell inside the `onnegotiationneeded` function if it has been executed because the stream was added or removed? Because from reading the docs I couldn't find a state for that.

At the moment I am switching a flag when I do `pc.addStream` or `pc.removeStream`. This flag helps me to tell within `onnegotiationneeded` if it has been triggered by a stream remove or not.

But I was wondering if there is already such a property given by the browser's (Chrome 40 or Firefox 36) API?

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN documentation for the `onnegotiationneeded` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onnegotiationneeded) states:

> This should be set to a function you provide which is passed a single
>   parameter: an Event object containing the negotiationneeded event.
>   There's no additional information provided in the event; anything you
>   need, you can get by examining the properties of the
>   RTCPeerConnection.

So basically, you cannot do it by the callback alone. But you may be able to use it with the `onstreamadded` or `onstreamremoved` handler

You may find a comfortable solution for keeping track of added tracks and streams [here](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/1161).